# Use UUID in annotation interface as default value

Tags: java, java-8, java-annotations

is possible to use UUID in annotation attribute? I tried add UUID in annotation as attribute as you can see below but it gives me error `Attribute value must be constant.`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    String name() default "";

    UUID guid() default UUID.random(); // there I have error
}
```

I also tried at least null instad of random UUID but same error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Annotation documentation ([here's Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation)):

> Return types are restricted to primitives, String, Class, enums, annotations, and arrays of the preceding types.

<s>You could change your definition to</s>

```
String guid() default UUID.random().toString();
```

Thanks to Holger for pointing out: that won't work either. The error is telling you that the value has to be a [constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), i.e. not a method call at all.

Comment: You can not specify an expression like `UUID.random().toString()` as default value.

Comment: @Holger I also tried define constant with static final and there set value, but same result

Comment: To define a constant, it’s not enough to have a `final` variable, it also must have an initializer which is also a compile-time constant. It should be obvious that `UUID.random().toString()` can’t be a constant, semantically. You can use `String guid() default "";` and leave it up to the code using the annotation to generate a new random UUID when the string is empty.